# List Data Structure C# Efficiency

Tags: c#, .net, generics

at the moment I'm using a `List<short>` as a buffer to hold things for a while while a calculation is made to each value based on other values further down the buffer. I then realised that this probably wasn't very effecient as I have been told that `List<>` is a linked list so every time I do `whatever = myList[100];` the poor thing is having to jump down all the other nodes first to get to the value I want. I dont want to use a regular Array because I have got loads of `Add()` and `Remove()`s kicking around in other places in the code. So I need a class that inherits `IList<T>` but uses a regular array data structure. Does anyone know a class in .net that works this way so I dont have to write my own? I tried using ArrayList but it 'aint generic!

Comment: Honestly, I don't think you're going to have to stress too much about the efficiency. Any gains you get will be barely noticeable

Comment: `List<>` is not a linkedlist. `LinkedList<>` however is. You could've noticed that because it does make no sense to expose random access in a linked list.

Comment: Indexed access to a List is O(1) operation.

Comment: lol I didn't notice the linkedlist class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a `List<T>` is a generic collection, not a linked list. If you need add and remove functionality then `List<T>` is the implementation most people default to.

Comment: ok, thanks my idea that a List<> is a linked list was wrong :(

Comment: if thats the case is there any reason for the use of a regular array over the list?

Comment: For simplicity when you are only dealing with a fixed number & collection of objects

Comment: "optimised" is a bit of a joke :p. The List's internal array is initially allocated with 4 elements, and each time it's capacity is exceeded, a new array is allocated with double the previous size - and it's contents copied over. It's obviously not the best container for appending - it's just simpler to write than manually expanding arrays. The List<> is the analog of a C++ std::vector<>.

Answer (score 11):

`List<T>` doesn't use a linked list implementation.  Internally it uses an array, so it appears to be exactly what you need.  Note that, because it's an array, Remove/insert could be an expensive operation depending on the size of the list and the position item being removed/inserted - O(n).  Without knowing more about how you are using it, though, it's hard to recommend a better data structure.

Quoting from the Remarks section of the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

> The List(T) class is the generic equivalent of the ArrayList class. It implements the IList(T) generic interface using an array whose size is dynamically increased as required.

Answer (score 3):

`List<T>` is backed by an array, not a linked list. Indexed accesses of a `List<T>` happen in constant time.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to tvanfosson's correct answer, if you're ever unsure of how something works internally, just load up the [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and you can see exactly how things are implemented. In this case, drilling down to the indexer of `List<T>` shows us the following code:

```
public T this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        if (index >= this._size)
        {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        return this._items[index];
    }
    // ...
```

where you can see that `this._items[index]` is an array of the generic type `T`.

Comment: Because Reflector is no longer free, [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) and [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) are other free alternatives.